# Using users with different roles in Flask application

Tags: database, mongodb

I'm new to databases and MongoDB. And I don't fully understand how it all works. It would be great if someone explained me the following thing.

I made a small test website with Flask. The website is just a shared page, where every user can post their message. But messages are shown only after the administrator (moderator) approves them. Users can't edit or delete any messages, even their own messages. Only administrator can do that.

So the 'admin' user is created in a MongoDB full rights. This user is the user I connect my Flask project to Mongo database with. Like this:

```
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'f9YV6h3teytX'

app.config['MONGO_URI'] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/database",
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = "database",
app.config['MONGO_USERNAME'] = USERNAME,
app.config['MONGO_PASSWORD'] = PASSWORD
```

My question is should I created a 'user' user in my database for non-admins? So they can't edit or delete anything from the DB? If yes, then how to I connect my Flask- app through the other user of the database? Or should I limit users with just Flask and not database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: your mongodb user credentials for connect the mongodb. Not for the make changes based on different roles For that you have to build schema for your project.

You mentioned that your building the message platform

Schema for users collection

```
{
        name xxx,
        email xxx@xxx.com
        password xxxx
        role XXXXX (admin,"non-admin")
}
```

so here role is important, for your platform two users exists (admin,normal-users)

- 1.first user login

  2. create the session or tokens for users based on role
  3. when user post the message check the user is login or not and check the role

     if user role is admin or non-admin they can create the messages
  4. when user try the edit or delete the messages check user is login or not and check the user role is admin or not

if role is not admin then terminate the session otherwise do the process